# Lucene indexing on Hadoop file system (HDFS)

Tags: hadoop, indexing, solr, lucene, hdfs

I am in a need to merge the Lucene indexes kept on HDFS. Wrote the customized version of the normal merge tool provided by Lucene. Code base is given below

```
HdfsDirectory mergedIndex =  new HdfsDirectory(new Path("/mergedindex"), new Configuration());
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(mergedIndex, new IndexWriterConfig(new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT))
    .setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE));

Directory[] indexes = new BaseDirectory[args.length - 1];
for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
  indexes[i  - 1] = new HdfsDirectory(new Path(args[i]), new Configuration());
}

System.out.println("Merging...");
writer.addIndexes(indexes);

System.out.println("Full merge...");
writer.forceMerge(1);
writer.close();
```

But it says it cannot get a HDFS lock on the directory because it is a timeout ! the time out value is hardcoded in the Lucene library as 1000 milli second.

> Exception trace
>     Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: org.apache.solr.store.hdfs.HdfsLockFactory$HdfsLock@21539796
>       at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:89)
>       at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:776)
>       at com.test.hadoop.solr.indexer.IndexMergeTool.main(IndexMergeTool.java:30)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Is there any  mechanism to overcome this so that I can merge the index on HDFS itself?

Thanks in advance,
Arun

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you delete the lock file under the index folder and try it.